# input fields alignment issues

Tags: html, forms, xhtml, css

input field are not getting aligned and they flow out of the container. What causes that? Here is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/6Eyef/) and [page](http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/mock1.html).  I need the labels aligned left and input field all aligned too. Is it ok to give -ve margins??

the .para#info div is flowing out of the page. It is supposed to sit parallel with `.para#news`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overdone your CSS and have many unneeded properties. 
Start by giving your label the following CSS properties, then style the inputs as you wish.

```
label {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 6px 6px 4px;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/6Eyef/1/

Comment: @hussein -- but I need the labels aligned left and input field all aligned

Comment: @hussei -- I tried it..its not working in my page. it works in fiddle.. when i did text-align;left I'm having the same problem

Comment: the .para#info div is flowing out of the page. It is supposed to sit parallel with .para#news

Comment: You don't have enough space, try to lowering padding on container or width on input.

Comment: You have too many things wrong with your CSS. Start styling from scratch and monitor how your form is changing as you go on.

Comment: @methyl -- I just removed all the form fields. If you c my page now, its not aligning parallel with .para#news

Comment: @Hussein -- <too many things wrong with your CSS> can you pls be more specific.

Comment: @Hussein - setting the base font-size to 62.5% will do any good??

Answer (score 1):

Its ok if you use..

```
margin-left: -220px;
margin-top: -150px;
```

for info Div.

---

thank you.

Comment: I've used the -ve margins to li .para#info ol li { margin: 0 10px 2px -25px;}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. But to align `<input>` elements with their labels, the `<label>` tags need to have to following CSS:

```
display: block;
float: left;
width: (a value)px;
```

And you need to add `clear: left` to the `<input>` elements

*Edit*: Hussein's answer is better